# FuelPHP - How to use Config::get($item) with a MySQL table?

Tags: php, fuelphp, data-mapping

I've created the table `config` with the default structure *[(from FuelPHP doc)](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/config.html#/config_groups)*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `config` (
  `identifier` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `config` longtext NOT NULL,
  `hash` char(13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`identifier`)
)
```

but now, **how can I access to that in my php code?**

`Config::get('DB.my_unique_indentifier')` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: `Config::get('name_of_config_value')` …?

Comment: It seems the version I had of fuelPHP didn't include /core/classes/config/db.php that's why it wasn't successful. I'm updated the core, and will update the post with the way to correctly access to the config when using a mysql table. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the `config.config` field (MySQL) needs to be a serialized array when using the .db extension!

---

**to load from the database:**

```
Config::load('visio.db'); // where visio is the config key.
```

**to save a new config:**

```
Config::save('visio.db', array('my_param' => 'my_value'));
```

**Here's my way to play with it:**

```
$config = Config::load('visio.db');
$jetons =& $config['jetons'];

$jetons += 10;
Debug::dump($jetons);
$config = Config::save('visio.db', $config);
```

---

Using `Config::load('visio.my_param.db')` doesn't work yet. This will may be implemented in FuelPHP 1.8 version.